# How to write WITH(CTE) within function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

I am trying to use "WITH" that is Common Table Expression within the function of PostgreSQL.

Here is the following example:

**Example**:

```
 Create or replace function withFunction() returns void as
 $Body$
 Begin
  WITH cmn_l1
  AS
  (
    SELECT "PhoneNumber1","PhoneNumber2",
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(Partition by "PhoneNumber1" Order By "PhoneNumber2" )FoundIn
    From tablename;
  )
 SELECT DISTINCT * INTO temptable
 FROM cmn_l1
 WHERE FoundIn > 1;

 end;
 $Body$
 language plpgsql;
```

**Question**: How to execute and get values into the above table using WITH within function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It it necessary to return `table`

```
Create or replace function withFunction()
returns table(phone1 text, phone2 text) as
```

then

```
select * from withFunction()
```

Comment: Okay. So there is no need to give EXECUTE or PERFORM statement before WITH?

Comment: @Meem `execute` is used for dynamic sql and `perform` when you don't want to return the result of the select

Comment: @ Clodoaldo Neto, Absolutely right. Thank you so much.