# Using WITH in a stored procedure, postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, common-table-expression, postgresql-8.4

I am working on table with a list of items. For every item there will be a parent item. So is a tree structure.

I need to get the full details of an item like ***Item 1 >> Item 1.1 >> Item 1.1.1 >> Item 1.1.1.1 >> Item 1.1.1.1.1*** So I decided to create a function which will return the details when we pass the id of the item, in the example id of ***Item 1.1.1.1.1***

```
CREATE TABLE item (
    item_id bigint,
    item_name text,
    item_code text,
    item_parentid bigint
);

INSERT INTO item VALUES (1, 'Item 1', 'Item 1', NULL);
INSERT INTO item VALUES (2, 'Item 1.1', 'Item 1.1', 1);
INSERT INTO item VALUES (3, 'Item 1.1.1', 'Item 1.1.1', 2);
INSERT INTO item VALUES (4, 'Item 1.1.1.1', 'Item 1.1.1.1', 3);
INSERT INTO item VALUES (5, 'Item 1.1.1.1.1', 'Item 1.1.1.1.1', 4);
```

So far i have got to write a query using 'WITH RECURSIVE' to retrieve the details. But didn't know how to write the same inside a function and return the item name.

```
WITH RECURSIVE itemtree (item_id, item_name, item_code,item_parentid,depth) AS (
            SELECT item_id,item_name, item_code,item_parentid,1 FROM item WHERE item_id = 5
            UNION
            SELECT child.item_id,child.item_name, child.item_code,child.item_parentid,depth+1 FROM item child
            INNER JOIN itemtree parent ON child.item_id = parent.item_parentid 
            )

SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(T.item_name), '>>>')  FROM (SELECT * FROM itemtree ORDER BY depth DESC) T;
```

I am using PostgreSQL `8.4.22`.

Comment: Look [here][http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html] at starting point, specially with `RETURN QUERY`

Comment: @Houari The difficulty is not to return the results. I can only find `SELECT INTO` keyword for executing the query and storing the result to a variable. But i was not been able to write the above query to `SELECT INTO` format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was rather simple. On first thought my idea was to execute the query and return the result using `SELECT INTO` or `EXECUTE` statements. 
But it was totally unnecessary. Thanks to another SO post, [How to write WITH(CTE) within function in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205381/how-to-write-withcte-within-function-in-postgresql). 
Now i have corrected the query and posted it below

```
--Have to add a new procedure to find the parent
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getitemname(itemid bigint) RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT
    AS $$
DECLARE
    item RECORD;
BEGIN  

    WITH RECURSIVE itemtree (item_id, item_name, item_code,item_parentid,depth) AS (
            SELECT item_id,item_name, item_code,item_parentid,1 FROM om_item WHERE item_id = $1 AND deleted = 0
            UNION
            SELECT child.item_id,child.item_name, child.item_code,child.item_parentid,depth+1 FROM om_item child
            INNER JOIN itemtree parent ON child.item_id = parent.item_parentid 
            )

    SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(T.item_name), '>>>') INTO item FROM (SELECT * FROM itemtree ORDER BY depth DESC) T;
    return item;

END;
$$;


SELECT getitemname(5);
```

Comment: So your question was how to do a function in Postgres

Answer (score 0):

You can write the query to an `INSERT INTO` format as:

```
INSERT INTO item_names
SELECT name
FROM
(
    WITH RECURSIVE itemtree (item_id, item_name, item_code,item_parentid,depth) AS (
        SELECT item_id,item_name, item_code,item_parentid,1 FROM item WHERE item_id = 5
        UNION
        SELECT child.item_id,child.item_name, child.item_code,child.item_parentid,depth+1 FROM item child
        INNER JOIN itemtree parent ON child.item_id = parent.item_parentid 
    )
    SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(T.item_name), ' >>> ') AS name FROM (SELECT * FROM itemtree ORDER BY depth DESC) T
) res
```

Comment: How can i execute this query and return the result from the function?

Comment: Thought your question was about `INSERT INTO`, saw your onw answer now